# How many blocks are required to make the toy?

Tags: geometry

A pyramid shaped toy is made by tightly placing cubic blocks of $1\times 1\times 1 cm^3$.The base of the toy is a square $4\times 4cm^2$. The width of each step is $0.5cm $.how many blocks are required to make the toy?

Let the number of blocks required be $x$ .then $x.1=4\times 4\times 0.5\implies x=8$

but the answer is $30$.Please help

Comment: If the base is to be covered with blocks, it is $16+9+4+1$.

Comment: The width is $0.5$ means the second step has dimension $(4-0.5-0.5)\times (4-0.5-0.5)=3\times3$, and so on.

Comment: @cr001; thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Number of Cubic block required for $4\times 4$ =$16$.  Similarly  Number of Cubic block required for $3\times 3$ =9 and 4 and 1 respectively .
Total= $16+9+4+1=30$

Answer (score 0):

HINT : Notice if the base has to be filled with blocks then number of blocks required is sum of the squares upto 4 so it is $4^2+3^2+2^2+1^2$=$30$.

Comment: I hope you know the reason.