# Blocks required to make the toy

Tags: geometry, area

A pyramid shaped toy is made by tightly placing cubic blocks of $1 \times 1 \times 1$ $cm^3$. The base of the toy is a square $4 \times 4$ $cm^2$. The width of each step is $0.5 cm$. How many blocks are required to make the toy?

What I didn't understand here is the width of each step. What do we mean by that?

We've been told the dimensions of each block.The width of block should be the width of each step. As steps must be blocks.

Please help.

I know it has been asked before. But I can't understand.

Ithink I can't understand the structure of the toy.

Comment: A similar question here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3636894/399263

Comment: This question has already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1533050). Also, @Shivani, you can search for duplicates on [Approach0](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://approach0.xyz/search/mobile.php&ved=2ahUKEwilh8211YrrAhVOb30KHXLWBWgQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw2GpJhpMgLJhaZBd3k5tO4t).

Comment: It simply means that each successive layer is shifted 1/2 block inward in both directions. The answer of @RossMillikan is spot on. Think about how bricks are normally laid even in a wall -- offset by half their length. Same thing here but in 2D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a $2D$ figure with $1 \times 1$ blocks (only three wide) and steps of $0.5$.  You have the same problem in $3D$
[image]

Comment: Where can I see that the width of each step is 0.5?

Comment: Look at the segment $NH$, for example.  It is $0.5$ wide.

Comment: What exactly is step size?

Comment: I am taking it as the width of the step from one layer to another.  It can't be vertical because blocks would fall down.  That is why I suggested $NH$